# Reading single char's into variables from file c++

Tags: c++, file, input, io

I am messing around with file input/output and I am trying to make a encoding/decoding program. I need help reading the encoded chars from the file back into the program to be decoded. (this is not an assignment, as I am only going into 9th grade next year, I am trying to do this because it seemed challenging.)
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
/* 
 * OUT: categorize words into char's, assign a symbol/number to each char, output number 
 *      combonation to file.
    IN: load file, decode file, read decoded version. */ 

using namespace std;

void Encode(){
        char message[100];
    char ENCODED[100];
    cout<<"input new content:\n>";
    cin.getline(message, 99);
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"encoding...\n";
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i){
             if (message[i]=='a') ENCODED[i]='1';
        else if (message[i]=='b') ENCODED[i]='$';
        else if (message[i]=='c') ENCODED[i]='!';
        else if (message[i]=='d') ENCODED[i]='*';
        else if (message[i]=='e') ENCODED[i]='2';
        else if (message[i]=='f') ENCODED[i]='&';
        else if (message[i]=='g') ENCODED[i]='^';
        else if (message[i]=='h') ENCODED[i]='%';
        else if (message[i]=='i') ENCODED[i]='3';
        else if (message[i]=='j') ENCODED[i]='=';
        else if (message[i]=='k') ENCODED[i]='_';
        else if (message[i]=='l') ENCODED[i]='-';
        else if (message[i]=='m') ENCODED[i]='2';
        else if (message[i]=='n') ENCODED[i]='9';
        else if (message[i]=='o') ENCODED[i]='4';
        else if (message[i]=='p') ENCODED[i]='|';
        else if (message[i]=='q') ENCODED[i]='/';
        else if (message[i]=='r') ENCODED[i]='>';
        else if (message[i]=='s') ENCODED[i]='?';
        else if (message[i]=='t') ENCODED[i]='}';
        else if (message[i]=='u') ENCODED[i]='5';
        else if (message[i]=='v') ENCODED[i]=',';
        else if (message[i]=='w') ENCODED[i]='.';
        else if (message[i]=='x') ENCODED[i]=';';
        else if (message[i]=='y') ENCODED[i]=')';
        else if (message[i]=='z') ENCODED[i]='@';
        else if (message[i]==' ') ENCODED[i]='#';
                else if (message[i] =='\0') {ENCODED[i] = '\}'; break;}
        else ENCODED[i]=' ';
    }
    cout<<"done encoding.\n";
    cout<<"exporting file...\n";
    ofstream OUTfile ("encoded.txt");
    OUTfile<<ENCODED;
    cout<<"file exported to parent directory.\n"; 
    cin.get();
}

void Decode(){ //this is where I run into problems!!
        string encoded[100]
    char DECODED[100]
    ifstream INfile ("encoded.txt");
    cout<<"Decoding...\n";
    INfile>>encoded;
    for (i=0; i<100; ++i){
             if (encoded[i]=='1') DECODED[i]='a';
        else if (encoded[i]=='$') DECODED[i]='b';
        else if (encoded[i]=='!') DECODED[i]='c';
        else if (encoded[i]=='*') DECODED[i]='d';
        else if (encoded[i]=='2') DECODED[i]='e';
        else if (encoded[i]=='&') DECODED[i]='f';
        else if (encoded[i]=='^') DECODED[i]='g';
        else if (encoded[i]=='%') DECODED[i]='h';
        else if (encoded[i]=='3') DECODED[i]='i';
        else if (encoded[i]=='=') DECODED[i]='j';
        else if (encoded[i]=='_') DECODED[i]='k';
        else if (encoded[i]=='-') DECODED[i]='l';
        else if (encoded[i]=='2') DECODED[i]='m';
        else if (encoded[i]=='9') DECODED[i]='n';
        else if (encoded[i]=='4') DECODED[i]='o';
        else if (encoded[i]=='|') DECODED[i]='p';
        else if (encoded[i]=='/') DECODED[i]='q';
        else if (encoded[i]=='>') DECODED[i]='r';
        else if (encoded[i]=='?') DECODED[i]='s';
        else if (encoded[i]=='}') DECODED[i]='t';
        else if (encoded[i]=='5') DECODED[i]='u';
        else if (encoded[i]==',') DECODED[i]='v';
        else if (encoded[i]=='.') DECODED[i]='w';
        else if (encoded[i]==';') DECODED[i]='x';
        else if (encoded[i]==')') DECODED[i]='y';
        else if (encoded[i]=='@') DECODED[i]='z';
        else if (encoded[i]=='#') DECODED[i]=' ';
                else if (encoded[i] =='\0') {DECODED[i] = '\}'; break;}
        else DECODED[i]==' ';
    } 
    cout<<"Decoded file content: "<<DECODED;
    cin.get();
}


int main(){
    string choice;
    cout<<"Encode new message or decode previous file?\n> ";
    cin>>choice;
    cin.ignore();
    if (choice=="encode") Encode();
    if (choice=="decode") Decode();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have no idea what I am doing when it comes to the Decode function.
ANY help would be appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT:** I updated the code with the suggestions provided, but When the compiler gets to the line " INfile>>encoded;" it says there is no match for operator ">>" in "INfile>>encoded"...

Comment: "As you can see, I have no idea what I am doing when it comes to the Decode function" Unfortunately, same holds true for the endode function as well: `are` and `you` are not useful as far as character literals go.

Comment: Take a look at this first.  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology

Comment: If you are expected to encode "are" and "you" as a single character, this is a relatively tricky assignment. This is homework, right?

Comment: no I am going to be a freshman next year... I just do this for fun.

Comment: Did you enter this code via speech recognition software? ;-)  'are' is clearly intended as 'r', and 'you' is clearly intended as 'u'.

Comment: 'are' and 'you' are not doing what you expect. These are multi-character constants and will be treated as an integer. When compared with a character they will never match.

Comment: I have an extension on my browser that converts "r" and "u" to "are" and "you" so people don't sound as dumb on the internet. hahaha

Comment: I'd suggest you to use lookup table than using the big if else block - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table . Alternatively, you can use some simply mathematical formula or binary operators to twist your data. You can reverse the same logic while decoding! in addition, better to check the length of the string rather iterating through the size of the array.

Comment: how would I check the size of the string? I thought about doing it that way but I don't know how... Also, I know that my code is sloppy, but I don't know how to use a "lookup table" or "mapping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

Compilation failed (g++-4.5.1) with no suitable overload of the `ifstream` constructor found, needs `name.c_str()`.

```
ifstream INfile (name);
```

There are semicolons missing on the next two declarations

```
char encoded[100]
char DECODED[100]
```

The loop counter `i` is undeclared (`for(int i = 0; ...`)

```
for (i=0; i<100; ++i){
         if (encoded[i]=='1') DECODED[i]='a';
```

From here on, you're comparing `DECODED[i]` to character constants, not assigning them. Replace all these `DECODED[i]==` by `DECODED[i] =`.

```
    else if (encoded[i]=='$') DECODED[i]=='b';
    else if (encoded[i]=='!') DECODED[i]=='c';
    else if (encoded[i]=='*') DECODED[i]=='d';
```

One further problem is that you encode and decode 100 characters, no matter whether the actual message is shorter. In both, `Decode()` and `Encode()`, add a check for the end of the string

```
if (array[i] =='\0') {
    other_array[i] = '\}';
    break;
}
```

to end the conversion.

Comment: Thank you! I realize I made some really stupid mistakes. I didn't go through my code carefully before posting, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that you do not understand the difference between char and string. A char is a letter or symbol, like 'a' 'b' 'c' '1' '0' '^' ( etc. But a string - it as a sequence of chars, like "abc" "123" "*&^" etc. In C/C++ to specify a char we use single quote, like 'a'. A value inside single quotes can only have one letter inside. To specify a string we use double quotes, like a mentioned before. A value inside double quotes may have as many characters as you want.

Comment: sorry for the confusion... My browser changed "r" and "u" to "are" and "you". I understand what chars and strings are.

Comment: okay. Than the problem is here "INfile>>encoded". Since encoded is an array of chars the programm read only one character from the file. Not the entire string. Consider changing the type of encoded to std::string

Comment: okay, that would solve the problem of getting all of the encoded letters back into the program, but then how do i examine/change them one by one if they are in a string? thanks.

Comment: using the same way. string has operator[] which gives you access to chars.

Comment: oh so if I do:  if (encoded[0]=='a') DECODED[0]='1';
that will do the trick? I thought the string array only gave you access to a certain "word" in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an exercise for yourself, may I suggest that you create a mapping to avoid those crazy if-statements (and make it easier to modify your encodings later):

```
// Warning: always address these with ints or unsigned char, not char
// if you expect extended ASCII characters
static unsigned char encode_map[256] = {0};
static unsigned char decode_map[256] = {0};

void InitEncodingMap()
{
    encode_map['a'] = '1';
    encode_map['b'] = '$';
    encode_map['c'] = '!';
    encode_map['d'] = '1';
    // etc...
    encode_map['z'] = '@';
    encode_map[' '] = '#';

    // Create the reverse map
    for( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
        unsigned char encoded = encode_map[i];
        if( decode_map[encoded] != 0 ) {
            printf("Collision for mapping %c -> %c\n", (char)i, encoded );
        } else {
            decode_map[encode_map[i]] = (unsigned char)i;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, try rewriting your Encode and Decode functions to use these maps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I have never worked with mappings before,,. I'll look into it.